# Puppet-lint works fine on command line in VM but not within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I have a VM running on which I was trying to run puppet-lint. I have Jenkins running on the same VM.

When I SSH to the VM and run puppet-lint, I see puppet-lint errors and warnings.
However, when I go to the Jenkins console (running on the same VM), I see 0 errors and warnings.

PS: I tried running as root as well and Jenkins user on command line!

Comment: We need more information about how you are executing puppet-lint from within Jenkins.

Comment: Here is the puppet code which i am using  https://github.com/sumitkaul/control-repo.git and for jenkins installed static analysis collector plugin

Rake plugin

Warnings Plug-in  , these 3 plugins and in configure option -> Scan for compiler warning -> select parser ( puppet-lint)   and then Scan for workspace files - > File Pattern ( **/*.pp) and parser ( puppet-lint)

Comment: Scan for compiler warning is in Post Build Actions.